# Swagger codgen: How to add additional attributes in swagger codgen

Tags: angular, spring-boot, swagger-codegen

I have been using `Swagger Codegen` to generate models from the backend to frontend (`Spring Boot` -> `Angular`) and I don't know how to add additional attributes automatically to generated frontend models.
Below is an example, the frontend model has additional attribute "Mode[]"

For example:

- backend model:

```java
    @Entity
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @Getter
    @Setter
    public class Project {
    
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Column(name = "id_project")
        private Long idProject;
    
        private String name;
    
        @JsonBackReference
        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "project")
        private List<Subproject> subprojects;
        
        @ManyToOne
        @ApiModelProperty(dataType = "long")
        @JoinColumn(name = "client_id_client")
        private Client client;
    
    }*
```

- frontend model:

```js
    export interface Project {
      idProject: number;
      name: string;
      client: Client;
      **modes: Mode[];**
      subprojects: Subproject[];
    }
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it just doesn't allow that and it shouldn't. it was made to make it easy to consume your API. if you need additional fields I would recommend you to make extension of the interface that you got from codegen.

```
 export interface ProjectData extends Project {
   modes: Mode[]:
 }
```

it would even be a stricter typings for you app as you would have separate types for just what you get from API.

```
http.get<Project>(url).pipe(map(enrichWithModes))
...
enrichWithModes(project: Project): ProjectData {
  // ....
return {...project, modes: []}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using OpenAPI spec v3, `additionalProperties` is default to true:

> additionalProperties - Value can be boolean or object. Inline or
> referenced schema MUST be of a Schema Object and not a standard JSON
> Schema. Consistent with JSON Schema, additionalProperties defaults to
> true.

Ref: https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/3.0.3.md#properties

Ideally the swagger codegen should support this by default so that model can store additional properties conforming to the specification. If it doesn't, you may file a bug report with Swagger Codegen.